# Proper pattern for Python `requests` result checking?

Tags: python, python-requests

I find my code scattered with this pattern:

```py
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
if response.status_code == 429:
    # sleep and try again until some limit
elif response.status_code != 200:
    response.raise_for_status()
result=response.json()
```

Of course, I can make my own wrapper function, but ... this seems like a really common thing. Is there an existing slightly-higher-level call that already exists that I should be using?

Comment: I think this depends on what endpoint/website you are trying to access. There are a multitude of status codes that could be thrown (not to mention that each website can throw whatever status code it wants, there is no restriction), and each status code means something different. For example, what would you consider 302 (Redirect) to be? A success, or a failure?

Comment: You don't need the `elif response.status_code != 200` check - `raise_for_status()` will only raise for status codes >= 400 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`Requests` provides access to `urllib3`'s `Retry` class which allows you to create a session which will retry connections based on a variety of situations.

The following demonstrates retrying when getting `429` status back:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

##### optional logging - only needed here to show retries is working #####
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
req_log = logging.getLogger('requests.packages.urllib3')
req_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
req_log.propagate = True
##### end logging #####

s = requests.session()
# total defaults to 10 - omit backoff_factor to retry as fast as possible
retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=2, status_forcelist=[ 429 ])
# Associate this session with urls starting with https://
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

# See https://httpbin.org/#/Status_codes for details (takes a comma-separated list of codes to return at random)
response = s.get("https://httpbin.org/status/429")
print(response)
```

Comment: Okay,  so I guess really "use `session`" is the key thing here.